# Linux Embedded Controller editor

Tags: linux, windows, performance, ide, embedded

Does anyone know of an Embedded Controller editor for Linux?
I currently use [Read & Write Utility](http://rweverything.phpnet.us/)
When using Windows to set my fan between 25%-50% because without it my laptop idles at 50°c

When using Linux however the fan simply never turns on and the computer turns off because of overheating after two minutes.

I already know what byte to edit on the Controller I just don't know of an Embedded Controller editor for Linux.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: The word "editor" can be ambiguous without a modifier.  Most people think of *text* editor.  You seem to asking about a memory hex editor.  Such a capability is more common in boot or memory programs, e.g. U-Boot, than under a kernel that protects memory.  **You are really asking an XY question.**  Why not try to turn on the fan in the bootloader, before memory protection, i.e. the MMU, is enabled?

Answer (score 2):

You can use vim and xxd:

```
vim -b some_binary_file
```

The `-b` open it in binary mode - vim won't put a newline at the end of the file when you save it.

Once you have it open, do

```
:%!xxd
```

Say you have a text file with these contents:

```
  Hello there this is a test blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

Running `:%!xxd` in vim will produce hex output like this:

```
1 0000000: 4865 6c6c 6f20 7468 6572 6520 7468 6973  Hello there this
2 0000010: 2069 7320 6120 7465 7374 2062 6c61 6820   is a test blah 
3 0000020: 626c 6168 2062 6c61 6820 626c 6168 2062  blah blah blah b
4 0000030: 6c61 6820 626c 6168 2062 6c61 6820 626c  lah blah blah bl
5 0000040: 6168 0a                                  ah.
```

To edit a byte, edit the hex value you want, and then run

```
:%!xxd -r
```

To convert the hex bytes back to binary format.

For example, changing the first `0x48` byte to `0x4a` in the hex output above:

```
1 0000000: 4a65 6c6c 6f20 7468 6572 6520 7468 6973  Hello there this
2 0000010: 2069 7320 6120 7465 7374 2062 6c61 6820   is a test blah 
3 0000020: 626c 6168 2062 6c61 6820 626c 6168 2062  blah blah blah b
4 0000030: 6c61 6820 626c 6168 2062 6c61 6820 626c  lah blah blah bl
5 0000040: 6168 0a                                  ah
```

and then running `:%!xxd -r` will convert the hex bytes back to binary format, which gives you this:

```
Jello there this is a test blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If your Embedded Controller is based on BusyBox,
then there is a very small version of vi.